# Adding method parameter name with javassist

Tags: java, reflection, javassist

How can I add method parameter names to a method, when none exists?

There are some examples on how to retrieve these names, if they exist, with a method like this:

```
CtMethod m;
CodeAttribute codeAttribute = m.getMethodInfo().getCodeAttribute();
if (codeAttribute != null) {
    LocalVariableAttribute table = (LocalVariableAttribute) codeAttribute.getAttribute(LocalVariableAttribute.tag);
    if (table != null)
        for (int i = 0; i < table.tableLength(); i++)
            m.getMethodInfo().getConstPool().getUtf8Info(table.nameIndex(i));
}
```

This will give all the parameter names of a method, if they exist.

How can I do the reverse?

Comment: If I may, why would you change the name of parameter in a compiled method?

Comment: Practically I don't want to change it. I want to add it if it does not exist. The original concept is that, the setBody(String) method removes not only the code but everything from a method, including the parameter names, see https://github.com/jboss-javassist/javassist/issues/146 .  I want to reverse this bad artifact.

Comment: I get the buggy situation, however I still don't get why you need this info to be attached to a compiled class. First I think that those info are not always persent but they are based on the compilation settings and second you can access with Javassist all the parameters just using several identifiers starting with $ have special meaning. take a look here https://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/tutorial/tutorial2.html

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean, but it is a strong requirement for a specific library, which in general there is no problem but in some edge cases this info needs to be preserved. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

> Javassist does not allow to remove a method or field, but it allows to
> change the name. So if a method is not necessary any more, it should
> be renamed and changed to be a private method by calling setName() and
> setModifiers() declared in CtMethod.
>
> Javassist does not allow to add
> an extra parameter to an existing method, either. Instead of doing
> that, a new method receiving the extra parameter as well as the other
> parameters should be added to the same class. For example, if you want
> to add an extra int parameter newZ to a method:
>
> `void move(int newX, int newY) { x = newX; y = newY; }`
>
> in a Point class, then you should add the following method to the Point class:
>
> void move(int newX, int newY, int newZ) {
>
> ```
> // do what you want with newZ.
> move(newX, newY);
> ```
>
> }

for more information, check this https://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/tutorial/tutorial2.html

Comment: Javassist allows to remove both a method and a field. But anyway this is not the question asked. I want to an existing method with no names in parameters to add a name to an existing parameter, without changing the number of parameters. This is practically meta-info.

Comment: @Panayotis  Please check the second paragraph I write : Javassist does not allow to add an extra parameter to an existing method,

Comment: As I said, I don't want to modify the number of parameters.

Comment: how can you define a method which have parameters but  parameters are no name ?

Comment: If you remove the debugging information, the parameters have not explicit names - don't have in mind what you write as Java code, but what exists inside the .class file.

Comment: BTW to modify the number of parameter would mean just to add another method

Comment: I am confused. If I write a method with parameters, then after compile, it will still have parameter name in `.class`. I can't image what the situation you said. Please add a concrete example.

Comment: No they won't always be there. For example, as I said in a previous comment, if you remove the debugging information no parameter names will be preserved.

Comment: I just know that the parameters will be changed to `arg0`, `arg1`, etc after compile. But no-name, which you said, it is unimaginable...

Comment: These names are generated, they don't actually exist.