# How to loop through Javassist StackMapTable?

Tags: java, javassist

Referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45995417/how-to-create-or-retrieve-a-stackmaptable-in-javassist), I still do not get the idea of looping through StackMapTable although I am able to get the Walker

```
StackMapTable stackMapTable = (StackMapTable) instructionToVisit.toCodeAttribute().getAttribute(StackMapTable.tag);

StackMapTable.Walker walker = new StackMapTable.Walker(stackMapTable);
```

Since integrating Javassist into [the project](https://github.com/amyjko/whyline/tree/master), I am assuming that StackMapTablehttps://www.javassist.org/html/javassist/bytecode/StackMapTable.html is equivalent to [StackDependencies](https://github.com/amyjko/whyline/blob/master/edu/cmu/hcii/whyline/bytecode/StackDependencies.java)

But I am not sure, is it able to be written like the [for-loop block in this class](https://github.com/amyjko/whyline/blob/master/edu/cmu/hcii/whyline/analysis/ValueSourceAnalyzer.java#L460)

I tried to understand how to use Javassist StackMapTable to loop through dependencies in the Stack memory of Java. Besides that, I was hoping to get a validation whether my assumption on replacing Javassist StackMapTable to the existing Whyline StackDependencies.

Comment: What makes you think that `StackMapTable` and `StackDependencies` are equivalent? Because there’s “stack” in the name?

Comment: That's exactly it. I was trying to remove custom code since implementing Javassist into the project.